# Why is P the head of PP?

Tags: syntax, prepositions, phrases

I was wondering what arguments there were to know that P is the head of a phrase [P + N].

As far as **adjunct phrases** are concerned, we can clearly see that as Ps select Ns (*during the rock; *in the Internet (English isn't my first language, I just assume that's the case based on what I've read and heard), etc.).

But what about **Ps being selected by Vs**? The following question can be posed: What selects Ns?
Let's take the phrase *to discriminate against rocks* for example. We can find its counterparts without a preposition in other languages. They will presumably all exhibit quite identical selectional properties (e.g. an object being discriminated against can't be inanimate), so I find it unreasonable to assume that some semantic features that define "discrimination" are part of the verb in one language but part of the preposition in the other. For if we assume that, we'll be forced to posit lots of homonymous prepositions to account for various sets they combine with.

The same argument can be used in respect to theta-roles (a beneficiary is unlikely to be a non-living thing).

At the same, there are situations in which the same theta role can be introduced by more than two prepositions for a given verb (to think about v. to think of), and these prepositions may have different sets of selection. If we assume that Vs select Ns via Ps then we will have to create homonymous verbs.

The third option that I find appealing is to assume two levels of selection, the first one being that of Vs, the second one - of Ps.

P.S. *One indication of Ns not selectiong Ps comes from causative prepositions in Russian. There's a pair of them (из-за & благодаря) that expresses the speaker's attitude to the desirability of the cause. If Ns determine Ps then their selection occurs beyond them as "desirability" is common for every N so that it doesn't differentiate anything, and is distant from not only their semantics but also from their connotations (which is directed at what they denote).*

I hope more competent people comment on that and give a more elaborate explanation if mine wasn't complete and comprehensive.

Comment: Not an answer, but we can discriminate _between_ rocks which still involves discriminating but not *against* anyone/thing. In your *think about* and *think of* example, there is a difference in meaning. Thinking about something involves some kind of prolonged consideration, where as *thinking of* merely means summoning something to mind.

Comment: @Araucaria-him I took _to discriminate against_ as an example but _between_ which includes, I believe, a different theta-role. Also _to think of/about_: I had in mind a Russian example: _говорить о/про_. Of course one can find differences between them but they basically involve the same theta-role. That's what I intended to put the emphasis on.

Comment: discriminate and discriminate against mean different things.

Comment: Heads are identified in terms of distribution. The word/element that most determines the distribution of the phrase is the head of the phrases. Prepositional phrases have a distribution that is distinct from that of noun phrases, hence the preposition must be the head. If the noun were the head instead, prepositional phrases would not be prepositional phrases, but rather they would be noun phrases. That would make no sense.

Comment: Concerning the example _discriminate against_, one can assume it is not necessarily verbs per se that select their arguments, but rather predicates do that. Thus, the predicate is not _discriminate_ alone, but rather it is the two-word combination _discriminate against_.

Comment: @TimOsborne, that's what I'd like to know more about the distribution. PP can be selected by a verb, just like NN can, and both can function as adjuncts (_I played football that night_ _and I played football at night_). Does it all come down to modification?

Comment: Consider examples like _Tuesdays are good_ and _*On Tuesdays are good_. If _Tuesdays_ were the head in both cases, the expectation would be for both sentences to be grammatical, which is clearly wrong. The same holds for objects, e.g. _I like Tuesday_ vs. _*I like on Tuesday_.  Again, if _Tuesday_ were the head instead of _on_, both of these sentence should be good, which is clearly wrong. Hence _on_ must be the head.

Comment: In your examples, you are dealing with adjuncts. Crucially, adjuncts semantically select their head. So in _I played football that night_, the adjunct _that night_ is semantically selecting the verb as its head. The verb does NOT semantically select the adjunct. The same holds for _I played football at night_, where the adjunct _at night_ is semantically selecting its head, not vice versa. That is the nature of adjuncts. Semantic selection points in the opposite direction from what one encounters with complements.

Answer (score 1):

Let me answer your question from the point of view of German grammar. German, like English, has so-called "prepositional objects", i.e. the verb selects a particular preposition, which has to introduce the object. In a language like German, you see that this preposition in turn assigns case to the noun. So there is a selection chain, and nothing speaks against having the P as the head of the verb's complement, since P visibly governs its own complement in turn. There is also a relation between the verb and the participant expressed by the noun, but this is in terms of semantic roles, and case government is distinct from that. The preposition can be a head and still be meaningless. So the meaning relation is between the verb and the PP, in which the P does not interfere. This is more or less the definition of a prepositional object; a phrase with a fixed and governed preposition, the semantics of the preposition is not active.

Having said that, there is of course a grey area between prepositions and case markers, and this indeed means blurring the difference between the directions in which dependencies run: case is a *feature of the N*, and a preposition is a governor that embeds the N. The grey area starts with English "of". I understand that the "of-genitive" is indeed analysed as a PP with "of" as a P-head. It just functions like a genitive of the noun. But ok, we can distinguish the syntactic structure from the function. It is still true that the function is performed by a word "of" that embeds a whole NP, in contrast to what a case feature would do (or often be taken to do).

Comment: @Alazon thanks for the reply. So you main point is government. I thought of it too but forgot to include in my original post. There are languages, like Welsh, that have inflecting prepositions. Suppose agreement is initiated by nouns. How are we then to make sense of the headedness of P?

Comment: Welsh P agrees with a following pronoun, which, however can be dropped: "ar" (= on), "arno" or "arno fe" (= on-it  it). It is the typical thing for person agreement to be triggered by a phrase that is governed by the agreeing head. So this case is entirely in line and supports the analysis that P is the head in the combination "on it".

Comment: Indeed, when you speak of an "inflected preposition" (inflected for person, a pronominal category), you are presupposing that P is the head -- otherwise you would call "it" a pronoun in some adverbial case (for example, "on it" with "it" as the head would have to be a pronoun "it" in the "superessive" case, as in Hungarian :)

Comment: I understand why the analysis of inflecting Ps as heads doesn't contradict a previous account of Ps but it's not the only option: adjective-noun agreement but now that I'm thinking about it, the head triggers agreement on the adjunct which is not the case for verbal agreement. But here we're dealing with Head-Complement, so what kind of agreement can we choose for it?

Comment: The generalisation was about person agreement. Adjective-noun agreement is a different construction from head-complement, yes, but lo & see: there is no agreement in the feature person.

Comment: The generalisation is from: Johanna Nichols: Person as an inflectional category. In: Linguistic Typology, 21-3 (2017), 387–456. (p. 393).